# sequelize-postgres Error code 91

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

If you use [sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) as your ORM with postgres database, you may see this error code, especially for first-timer, including me. Found out the problem from [this discussion](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/364) .
Just define the 'port' property with 5432 (default postgres port) will fix the problem.

```
    var orm = new sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {   
      dialect: 'postgres',   
      host: 'localhost',   
      port: '5432' /* define database port */ 
    });
```